# Manjaro / Plasma - CPU cores overload and get stuck at 100% one by one when cloning a big git repo

Tags: linux, nvidia, git, manjaro, plasma5

First of all, I'm not a linux expert, I'm trying to figure out as I go but sometimes it's more than I can handle.

I've been trying to get a manjaro 22.1.3 (Talos) (kernel 6.1) to work for about a week now. Previously I had manjaro 21.2.1 (kernel 5.15) which worked fine but when I formatted and upgraded, errors started happening.

This manjaro is one of the guest OSs of an arch host.

The problems started when I first installed manjaro, I selected the open source drivers, which when I booted the OS made all my cores get stuck on 100%, slowly, one by one, and the applications started to freeze one by one until the system was absolutely unusable and I had to force shutdown the guest OS on the host. This happened when I was cloning a huge repo which was the whole reason for that guest OS existing.

Then I formatted that partition and reinstalled manjaro using the proprietary drivers, which worked perfectly and seemed to have fixed the whole issue. I was able to clone the repo and start working on it. Until I started having problems with `baloo-file-extractor` which hogged the system's memory like it was the only relevant process. Many other people seem to have had enough with it and suggested a forced manual removal of all baloo-related files, which made me run:

```
sudo find / -type f -name '*baloo*' -delete
```

After that manjaro was running like the wind. That's when I deleted the repo and tried cloning it again (may have been a mistake but I needed to be sure). And that brought all the problems back up again. One by one, each core explode to 100% and stay stuck forever. Applications one by one get stuck too, even the network manager.

So I don't know anymore what is the problem. nvidia? baloo? git? the manjaro/plasma mix?

Can anybody shed any kind of light on this? I'm starting to lose my hair over this.

Here is some helpful info (if you need anything else please let me know):

```
# sudo inxi -Fazy
  System:
    Kernel: 6.1.30-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.1
      parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64
      root=UUID=74c20d02-d0eb-47b1-bdff-46aeca800c85 rw quiet splash
      udev.log_priority=3
    Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.4 tk: Qt v: 5.15.9 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM
      Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux
  Machine:
    Type: Vm-other System: Dell product: XPS 8500 v: pc-q35-5.2 serial: N/A
      Chassis: QEMU type: 1 v: pc-q35-5.2 serial: N/A
    Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A UEFI: Dell v: Default System date: N/A
  CPU:
    Info: model: Intel Core i9-10900K bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Comet Lake
      gen: core 10 level: v3 note: check built: 2020 process: Intel 14nm family: 6
      model-id: 0xA5 (165) stepping: 5 microcode: 0xF6
    Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 10 tpc: 2 threads: 20 smt: enabled cache:
      L1: 1.2 MiB desc: d-20x32 KiB; i-20x32 KiB L2: 40 MiB desc: 10x4 MiB
      L3: 16 MiB desc: 1x16 MiB
    Speed (MHz): avg: 3696 min/max: N/A base/boost: 2000/2000 cores: 1: 3696
      2: 3696 3: 3696 4: 3696 5: 3696 6: 3696 7: 3696 8: 3696 9: 3696 10: 3696
      11: 3696 12: 3696 13: 3696 14: 3696 15: 3696 16: 3696 17: 3696 18: 3696
      19: 3696 20: 3696 bogomips: 147896
    Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
    Vulnerabilities:
    Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
    Type: l1tf status: Not affected
    Type: mds status: Not affected
    Type: meltdown status: Not affected
    Type: mmio_stale_data status: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no
      microcode; SMT Host state unknown
    Type: retbleed mitigation: Enhanced IBRS
    Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
      prctl
    Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
      sanitization
    Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Enhanced IBRS, IBPB: conditional, RSB
      filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: SW sequence
    Type: srbds status: Unknown: Dependent on hypervisor status
    Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
  Graphics:
    Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER] vendor: ASUSTeK
      driver: nvidia v: 530.41.03 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm non-free: 530.xx+
      status: current (as of 2023-05) arch: Turing code: TUxxx
      process: TSMC 12nm FF built: 2018-22 pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
      bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1e81 class-ID: 0300
    Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 23.1.1
      compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X: loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia display-ID: :0
      screens: 1
    Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x1080 s-dpi: 81 s-size: 1204x343mm (47.40x13.50")
      s-diag: 1252mm (49.29") monitors: <missing: xrandr>
    API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 530.41.03 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080
      SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
  Audio:
    Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
      v: kernel pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.0
      chip-ID: 10de:10f8 class-ID: 0403
    API: ALSA v: k6.1.30-1-MANJARO status: kernel-api with: aoss
      type: oss-emulator tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
    Server-1: JACK v: 1.9.22 status: off tools: N/A
    Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.70 status: n/a (root, process) with: wireplumber
      status: active tools: pw-cli,wpctl
    Server-3: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active (root, process)
      with: pulseaudio-alsa type: plugin tools: pacat,pactl
  Network:
    Device-1: Intel 82574L Gigabit Network driver: e1000e v: kernel pcie: gen: 1
      speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:10d3
      class-ID: 0200
    IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Drives:
    Local Storage: total: 2.55 TiB used: 37.43 GiB (1.4%)
    ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Seagate model: Expansion size: 1.82 TiB
      block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B type: USB rev: 2.1 spd: 480 Mb/s
      lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 tech: N/A serial: <filter> fw-rev: 0712 scheme: GPT
    SMART Message: A mandatory SMART command failed. Various possible causes.
    ID-2: /dev/vda maj-min: 254:0 model: N/A size: 750 GiB block-size:
      physical: 512 B logical: 512 B tech: N/A serial: N/A scheme: GPT
    SMART Message: Unknown smartctl error. Unable to generate data.
  Partition:
    ID-1: / raw-size: 749.7 GiB size: 736.87 GiB (98.29%) used: 37.43 GiB (5.1%)
      fs: ext4 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/vda2 maj-min: 254:2
    ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 300 MiB size: 299.4 MiB (99.80%)
      used: 288 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat block-size: 512 B dev: /dev/vda1 maj-min: 254:1
  Swap:
    Alert: No swap data was found.
  Sensors:
    System Temperatures: cpu: N/A mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 36 C
    Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0%
  Info:
    Processes: 328 Uptime: 10m wakeups: 0 Memory: available: 15.25 GiB
    used: 1.54 GiB (10.1%) Init: systemd v: 252 default: graphical
    tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 12.2.1 clang: 15.0.7 Packages: pm: pacman
    pkgs: 1126 libs: 323 tools: pamac pm: flatpak pkgs: 0 Shell: Zsh (sudo)
    v: 5.9 default: Bash v: 5.1.16 running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.27
```